# Finding negative values in SLL

Tags: c++

I'm required to traverse through a singly linked list and find the negative nodes, delete them and return the number of delete nodes.

This is the code i have so far, but I always get counter=1 returned from the function

Is there anything wrong in the for loops and if statements, or is it something else

```
bool IntSLList::DeleteNegativeNodes()
{
int counter=0;
if(IsEmpty() == true)
    counter++;

if(head->val<0)
{
    DeleteFromHead();
    counter++;
}

if(tail->val<0)
{
    DeleteFromTail();
    counter++;
}


IntSLLNode *node, *pred, *tmp;
node = pred = NULL;


for(pred = head, node = head->next; 
    node != NULL; 
    node = node->next, pred = pred->next)
{
    if(node->val<0)
    {
        node->flag = 1;

    }
}
for(tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
{
    if(tmp->flag==1)
    counter++;
    delete tmp;


}
return counter;
}

int main()
{
int n,x,z;
IntSLList list1;


cout <<"Insert number of nodes u'd like inserted in list" << endl;
cin >> n;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin >> x;
    list1.AddToTail(x);
}
z=list1.DeleteNegativeNodes();

cout << "Number of negative deletes nodes is : " << z << endl;

 }
```

Comment: Maybe making counter static or global variable will help but notw you will have to reinitiate it every time in main if u r using it more than once in same program

Comment: `DeleteNegativeNodes` deletes all the nodes in the list and counts those with `tmp->flag==1` at `for(tmp = head`... ` loop. You forgot `{ }` inside the `if` statement.

Comment: Didn't change anything, i am still getting "Number of negative deletes nodes is : 1"

Comment: I've tried just having a list with 2 nodes including negative values at head and tail, I've received a value 1 for the counter as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the type of the return value. Check the signature of the method:

```
bool IntSLList::DeleteNegativeNodes()
```

Return type is `bool` there. When you return `counter` of type `int` from your method it's [implicitly converted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to `bool`. Zero value becomes `false`. All other values become `true`.

On the caller side:

```
z=list1.DeleteNegativeNodes();
```

`bool` value is implicitly converted to `int`. Because of it you get `1`.

Change the return type of `DeleteNegativeNodes` to `int` to fix the problem.

Comment: I can't believe i let that skip my mind.I have reprogrammed my DeleteNode, thats why i had this incident. Thanks alot for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: @HasanSammour Glad to help. If the answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the second for you have

```
if(tmp->flag==1)
```

And I think you have to use

```
if(node->flag==1)
```

Comment: I'm using a different loop with the node tmp to traverse through it